# Set alarm from notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, alarm

I need to add an alarm to mobile's clock app for which I'm sending user a notification. When user clicks on notification a new alarm should be added with given time.
Below is the code:

```
//Create intent
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, event.getEventName());
Calendar alarmTime = new GregorianCalendar();
alarmTime.setTime(new Date(event.getAlarmTime()));
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, alarmTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, alarmTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

//Create and show notification
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("MyAppsAlarm",
        "MyAppsAlarmNotifications",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
channel.setDescription("Channel to show notifs");
mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(main.getApplicationContext(), "Zzzzz")
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Alarm Helper")
        .setContentText(message)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setContentIntent(alarmPendingIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

When I click on notification nothing happens. Notification stays as it is while the notification drawer closes automatically.

I tried to fire the `intent` using `startActivity(alarmIntent);` and it works as expected but from notification `.setContentIntent(alarmPendingIntent);` seems to be doing nothing.

Comment: You have to use explicit intent in your PendingIntent.getBroadcast().

Comment: Can you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set an alarm using `AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM` then you have to use `PendingIntent.getActvity()` instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. `AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM` is an `Activity` ACTION.

If you don't want the UI of the alarm clock to be shown, you can add this to the `Intent`:

```
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use broadcast receiver in your app to receive broadcast when the user clicks on notification.

Let your broadcast receiver is NotifBroadCastReceiver

```
public class NotifBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @override
    void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
       //you can extract info using intent.getStringExtra or any other method depending on your send data type. After that set alarm here.
    }
}
```

So when create pending intent you can do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, BroadcastReceiver.class);
//set all the info you needed to set alarm like time and other using putExtra.
PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Now when user click on notification, you will receive the broadcast in onReceive of NotifBroadCastReceiver.

**NOTE** You have to register your broadcast receiver in manifest like

```
<receiver
        android:name="your broadcast receiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```